# Using tensorflow hub with go

Tags: tensorflow, go, tensorflow-hub

I want to use pre trained models in my go application. Especially the Inception-ResNet-v2 model.
This model seems to be only available via tensorflow hub (https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/).

However I could not find any documentation how to use tensorflow hub with the go language bindings for tensorflow.

How can I download and use these models in go?

Comment: i don't think go is officially supoprted by tensorflow anymore, you might find something on tensorflow forums / mailing lists

Comment: Ok thanks. After talking with some ML experts I was recommended using python for at least the parts of the application which are going to use tensorflow and I think that is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of work in the past few days I finally found a way.

At first I wanted to just use Python to do all the Tensorflow stuff and then provide the results via a rest service. However it turned out that the number of models provided by Tensorflow Hub is very small. This was a problem for me because I had to try out different models and compare them.

Thus I switched to using models from https://github.com/tensorflow/models. There are several tutorials how to export the data to .pb files. Those files can then be loaded in Go using gocv.

It requires a lot of work to convert the files, but in the end I think this is the best way to use Tensorflow models in go.

Comment: did you find out how to use the models  using `tensorflow/go` once they are imported using `gocv`?

Comment: I don't know anymore. Also a lot of things have changed between when the question was phrased and now. Mainly when I was doing this back in 2019 it was kinda hard situation because TF 1 was deprecated while TF 2 was not yet released. I never really managed to get everything to run as intended.

Maybe have a look at Keras, I also found out since that it might be a better alternative to TF.